# Proof of undecideability that one state is reached before another

Tags: reductions, undecidability

I'm trying to show that, for a deterministic Turing machine $M=(Q,\Gamma,\Sigma,\delta,q_0)$, the language $K$, which includes all of the words $w \in \Sigma^\ast$ where the calculation of $M$ on $w$ pass on the state $q$ before reaching $q'$, but if $q'$ is never reached then $w$ is not in $K$, is both recursively enumerable and undecidable.

I am thinking that this could be solved by a reduction of the Halting problem, but I do not know how to proceed.

Reducing the Halting problem to this problem would mean that a machine $M$ with data $w$ will halt on $w$ iff a machine $M'$ with data $w$ that first passes state $q$ then $q'$.
I see that if we were to associate $q$ in $M'$ with $q_0$ in $M$ and $q'$ in $M'$ with $q_f$ in $M$ we could associate part of the problem with the halting problem, but how can the condition "$q_f$ must not be reached first" be included?

Comment: Start by stating what it means from the halting problem to reduce to your problem. Often people get stuck since they skip this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us follow the hint given by Yuval.

**What is the halting problem?**

It is the problem of accepting the following language.

$$\text{HALT}= \{⟨M, w⟩ : M \text{ is a TM and }M\text{ will halt on input } w\}$$

**What is the current problem?**

It is the problem of accepting the following language.

$$\begin{align}
\text{One}&\text{StateBeforeAnother} 
= \{⟨M, q, q',w⟩: M\text{ is a TM} \\&\wedge q\text{ and } q'\text{ are two states of }M \\
&\wedge \left(M \text{ will reach } q' \text{ on input } w\right.\\
&\vee M \left.\text{ will reach } q \text{ before reaching } q' \text{ on input } w \right)\}
\end{align}$$

**How to define $\text{HALT}$ in a way similar to how $\text{OneStateBeforeAnother}$ is defined?**

The idea is that if we can formulate $\text{HALT}$ in a way similar to the way $\text{OneStateBeforeAnother}$ is defined, then we might reduce the former to the latter.

$M$ halts on input $w$ means $M$ reaches a halt state on input $w$. $\text{OneStateBeforeAnother}$ is about $M$ reaches $q$ and then $q'$.

Let us try brute pattern matching.

- Let $q$ be a halt state. $M$ reaches $q$, the halt state and then reaches $q'$. That cannot happen since the halt state is the last state. Sigh!
- Let $q'$ be a halt state. $M$ reaches $q$ and then reaches $q'$, the halt state. That makes sense. What is $q$ then? How about letting $q$ be the initial state of $M$?

  Great, we have just found the following reduction, where $q_0$ is the initial state of $M$ and $q'$ is the halt state of $M$ on input $w$.

  $$⟨M, w⟩\in\text{HALT} \to 
  ⟨M, q_0, q',w⟩\in\text{OneStateBeforeAnother}$$

  Wait, this is not a well-defined reduction as $q'$ cannot be known at the time of reduction since it depends on how $M$ runs on input $w$, the undecidable halting problem!

  I will leave you to conquer the problem above, how to require $q'$ to be a halt state without dependence to $M$ and $w$.

Comment: Isn't there a problem with defining q to be q$_0$? Is there a guarantee that M reaches q?

Comment: Given (the string that encodes) $M$, we can find $q_0$ in constant (or at most linear) time. If $q$ is the initial state, it has been always when $M$ begins to run since it is the initial state.

Comment: If it is too difficult to overcome the last obstacle, please check a further hint in the last paragraph of [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/revisions/6dc4c34f-8ceb-4dc2-bfeb-e440aa8441df/view-source).

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!